# Qt, openGL, widgets and offscreen rendering

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, double-buffering

I am developing on RedHat Linux, cat /etc/redhat-release:

```
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

I am using Qt Creator 4.3.1:

```
    Based on Qt 5.9.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)
```

The project I'm developing is using Qt 5.6.2 GCC 64bit, the project has been developed with graphical objects derived from QWidget, this includes a live video stream.

Unfortunately we have experienced tearing in the video whilst it is playing back and this is also evident in other widgets displayed around the video, I believe this is because the video is not using vsync.

I believe using openGL will rectify this situation, the aim is to rewrite the widgets including the video playback using openGL.  I've spent several days trying to find complete and working solutions but so far failed to find a complete and working solution.

I've been looking at using QOpenGLWidget, in a widget I am using to test:

```
    class clsElevStrip : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions {
    Q_OBJECT
```

In the constructor, I set-up the format for offscreen rendering:

```
    //Create surface format for rendering offscreen
    mobjFormat.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    mobjFormat.setSamples(4);
    mobjFormat.setVersion(3, 0);
    mobjFormat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
    setFormat(mobjFormat);
```

In the paintGL method:

```
    QOpenGLContext* pobjContext = context();
    QSurface* pobjSurface = pobjContext->surface();
    assert(pobjSurface != NULL);

    int intSB1 = pobjSurface->format().swapBehavior();
    qDebug() << (QString("paintGL:format: ")
               + QString::number(intSB1));
    pobjContext->makeCurrent(pobjSurface);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.0,  0.5, 0);
    glEnd();

    pobjContext->swapBuffers(pobjSurface);
```

Nothing is visible on the main display, the debug statement shows the format as 2 (DoubleBuffering).

If I comment out the line in the constructor:

```
    setFormat(mobjFormat);
```

The debug statement shows the format as 0 (DefaultSwapBehavior).  And the graphics are visible, what have I missed?

Comment: To save you later trouble when googling things: What you aim to do there is *double buffered* rendering, not off-screen rendering. Double buffering is, when you prepare an image in a back buffer and swap the back buffer to the screen scanout front buffer in the vertical retrace interval. *Off screen* rendering is, if you're rendering to a buffer that's not going to be shown directly on a display device, i.e. you intend to save the rendered image to a file without showing, or generating intermediary images that are post processed before shown.

Comment: @datenwolf, thank you, I've used offscreen rendering before to prepare graphics and then blit to the visible display (not using Qt or openGL), for our requirements the aim is to remove tearing in the video and graphics to give a smooth appearance.

Comment: Yes, that much has been clear. Using OpenGL and its swap interval extension (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Swap_Interval) is certainly a viable way to get V-sync correct display updates (be wary of compositing WMs, though). However if your goal is displaying video, then one of the dedicated video presentation APIs of your platform might be a proper choice either. On X11 that'd be one of Xv or XVVA(VAAPI) or VDPAU. All of them have vsync control.

Comment: @datenwolf, thank you, can you please clarify with an example what you mean, I am using Qt and openGL on RedHat, I'm not sure what you mean by "On X11 that'd be one of Xv or XVVA(VAAPI) or VDPAU" ?  At the moment, I don't have any visible video when DoubleBuffering is specified.

Comment: These are just alternative APIs, that you could use instead of OpenGL.

Comment: @datenwolf, thank you, but I'm sure there is a way to get the openGL wokring, I just need a good working example to look at, problem is I can't find one, one that is based on QOpenGLWidget, not Window and performs DoubleBuffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for your problem is simple:

Just do not all that QOpenGLGLContext jugging. The whole point of `paintGL` is, that this particular function is called inside a wrapper that already does all that context juggling for you. **There is no need to call `makeCurrent` or `swapBuffers`. Qt already does that for you!

From the Qt documentation

> ### `void QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()`
>
> This virtual function is called whenever the widget needs to be
>   painted. Reimplement it in a subclass.
>
> **There is no need to call makeCurrent() because this has 
>   already been done when this function is called.**
>
> Before invoking this function, the context and the framebuffer are
>   bound, and the viewport is set up by a call to glViewport(). 
>   No other state is set and no clearing or drawing is performed 
>   by the framework.

If you have just this as your `paintGL` it will show something, **iff you have either a *compatibility profile* >=OpenGL-3.x context OR if you're using a <=OpenGL-2.x context.** You're using the legacy fixed function pipeline there, which will *not* work with OpenGL-3.x core profile contexts!

```
void glwidget::paintGL(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.0,  0.5, 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: I thought the call to context() returns the context of the QOpenGLWidget class that paintGL is part of ?

Comment: According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#context, calling context returns a pointer to the context in the widget...not a new context.

Comment: I know this is true, because the context in paintGL has the same format as set in the contructor.

Comment: I've commented out both pobjContext->makeCurrent(pobjSurface); and pobjContext->swapBuffers(pobjSurface); but still nothing is displayed.  So now my paintGL matches yours, but still nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure why but editing the constructor and changing the format settings to just: mobjFormat.setSamples(16);
    mobjFormat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);  and now it displays.